# SQL column edit issue

Tags: sql-server

When i am going to change the data type of column name i am getting these error,,Can you tell me the solution

Saving changes is not permitted.The changes you have made require the following
.You have either made changes to a table that can't be created
or enabled the option Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created
..Where can i find the option "Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this in Tools -> Options -> Designers in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Should be the second last check box on that dialog